# Android location based system to record in Server

Tags: android, cordova, location, maps, server

We would like to implement a project which seems easy but however seeking your advices and guidance.

Would like to create an Android app.,
Once our users downloaded and installed APK file, they will sign-up via HTML - this part is OK. Once admin confirmed their registration, users sign-in. This part is also OKAY. Believe that even with phonegap we can handle this part.

But once they signed-in would like to record their location on a map and also willing to share the other users location on a map screen.

So the question is,
How we can save the location data into a server (which OS should be - and software to record last seen position) and any library or available script on hand.

Thanks a lot guys. Much appreciate yr comments.

Comment: i use php as webservice then save the location that send by client into my DB

Comment: understand. could u pls give me link to check?